# How to fix slow queries at one go?

Tags: mysql, performance

I've enabled slow query log in Mysql for the queries that take time more than `3` seconds. Now when I checked the log, there are more  than a hundred thousand slow queries logged. Now I want to fix these slow queries but these are too many to fix one by one. So how should I go about it ?

Is there any alternative to improve all the slow queries ?

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to provide more details: size of database, example queries that are slow, etc.

Comment: size of the production database is around  23GB.

Comment: You may find this utility very helpful.


https://www.eversql.com  Optimize Any SQL Query, Automatically - Trial available.

Comment: @WilsonHauck It asks to upload the schema but it's confidential and I can't share it.

Comment: Uploading of the schema is optional.  They will still provide suggestions for you to consider.

Comment: Yes it worked optimized 2 queries and then asked for purchasing it.

Comment: @SohaibAhmad Can you share your Slow Query Log?  If so attach it to an email to mydatalinks@mysqlservertuning.com and we will provide a few suggestions to assist.

Comment: You will now be able to analyze one query a month for life at no charge.

Answer (score 1):

You need to summarize your slow logs on a per-query-template basis. Put your log through either of the following:

1) mysqldumpslow -s t [path-to-file/filename.log]

2) pt-query-digest [path-to-file/filename.log]

and that will give you the query templates in order of significance of impact on performance. Fix the performance for one query of that pattern and you'll fix it for all of them.

Comment: You should run it on the slow log. You should probably pipe the output to a file, as it'll take a while and output will probably vastly exceed your terminal scrollback. Same for pt-query-digest.

Comment: Run it from your mysql \ bin folder.  And email the summary to me, please.

Comment: @SohaibAhmad - The summarization will probably show that only 10 queries that account for 70% of bad queries.  Fix those, then "rinse and repeat".